# How to trace transactions without sending them to the network?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have made several transactions and would like to test/trace them without waiting for the miner to generate a block. And without even sending them to the network without testing. How can this be do in geth?
I would like to test the transactions in the current head, before sending it to the network.

Comment: Did you consider using eth_call?

Comment: Ideally I would like to see logs and traces.```debug.traceTransaction("0xххххх", {tracer: 'callTracer', tracerConfig:{withLog: true}})```

Comment: Oh I see, then you best bet is likely debug_traceCall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [debug_traceCall](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-tracecall), which is a combination of `debug_` and `eth_call`.

It also supports built-in tracers, including `callTracer` that you mention.